# cakephp validation alphabet issue

Tags: php, cakephp

i have validated the letter field in below code but it doesnt work..

```
<?php
    class User extends AppModel {
      public $name = 'User';
      public $displayField = 'name';

      public $validate = array(
          'firstname'=>array(
              'Please enter your firstname.'=>array(
                  'rule'=>'[a-zA-Z]+',
                  'message'=>'Please enter your firstname.'
              )
          ),
?>
```

could somebody help pls

Comment: The "please fill out"-message may be the default behavior of your browser if a form field is a required field. You can try to set 'required' => false in your view template to disable the required-option while testing, so your AZ-error message should appear... We can help you better, if you give more information about the problem. How does the form view look like? What do you enter to test the validation, what browser and CakePHP-version are you using...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't ended your array and your class, which is most likely the issue.

```
<?php
    class User extends AppModel {
      public $name = 'User';
      public $displayField = 'name';

      public $validate = array(
          'firstname'=>array(
              'Please enter your firstname.'=>array(
                  'rule'=>'[a-zA-Z]+',
                  'message'=>'Please enter your firstname.'
              )
          )
      );
    }
?>
```

Comment: What exacly is your problem. Is the validation not running at all? Is it validating, but incorrectly? Are you getting any errors?